# How do I use a custom gradle build file and gradle settings file

Tags: gradle, build

The gradle command has a bunch of flags to customize its environment [1]. Among them are `--build-file` and `--settings-file`. But I can't seem to get them to work the way I expect them to.

I expected the following to work

```sh
$ cat <<-EOF > alt-settings.gradle
    rootProject.name = 'custom-name'
EOF
$ cat <<-EOF > alt-build.gradle
    task test { /* ... */ }
EOF
$ gradle \
    --settings-file alt-settings.gradle \
    --build-file alt-build.gradle \
    tasks --all
```

But this throws an exception

```
Build file './alt-build.gradle' is not part of the build defined by settings file './alt-settings.gradle'. If this is an unrelated build, it must have its own settings file.
```

If I omit `--settings-file` from the above command Things do work, and gradle picks up `alt-build.gradle`.

What is going wrong, and how do I fix this?

Ideally I would like to be able to run `gradle` even when there is a settings.gradle file that does not work. For instance in the following senario

```sh
$ cat <<-EOF > alt-build.gradle
    task test { /* ... */ }
EOF
$ cat <<-EOF > alt-settings.gradle
    rootProject.name = 'custom-name'
EOF

$ cat <<-EOF > settings.gradle
    This will not compile
EOF
$ cat <<-EOF > build.gradle
    This will not compile
EOF

$ gradle \
    --settings-file alt-settings.gradle \
    --build-file alt-build.gradle \
    tasks --all
```

[1] https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#environment_options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure the custom build file in your custom settings file and then only use the --settings-file parameter when calling gradle.

alt-settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'custom-name'
rootProject.buildFileName = 'alt-build.gradle'
```

alt-build.gradle:

```
task test { /* ... */ }
```

gradle call:

```
gradle --settings-file alt-settings.gradle tasks --all
```

This way the default build and settings files are not used at all and it does not matter if they work or not.

**Update for newer gradle versions (after comment by haridsv, tested with version 8.0.1):**

The gradle upgrading guide (https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html#configuring_custom_build_layout) gives a suggestion on how to handle custom build layouts.
You can use if statements in the settings file and/or in the build file to have different builds like so

```
if (System.getProperty("profile") == "custom") {
    println("custom profile")
} else {
    println("default profile")
}
```

The else branch contains your default build and you execute it by calling gradle like this:

```
gradle tasks --all
```

if you want to run the custom build you need to call gradle with the `-D` command line option. Like so:

```
gradle -Dprofile=custom tasks --all
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is an old question and I thought I'd never get any answers. So thank you.

Based on your suggestion I tried googling a bit more and I came across the following: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-change-project-name-when-using-non-build-gradle-build-file/4343/2

Perhaps it is a neat idea to include that in your answer. It will make `--build-file` work together with `--settings-file` if you included it in `alt-settings.gradle`.

Comment: Both of these options are marked as deprecated, any idea what are the alternatives? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:environment_options

Comment: updated answer for newer gradle versions